# web2py - extra_fields in auth_user doesn't show

Tags: python, python-2.7, web2py

If I create a new simple web2py application **test_auth** and I add in Models **my_tables.py** file with this code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#Add authentication to the app.
from gluon.tools import Auth

auth = Auth(db)

#Add some fields in auth db to have a complet user profile.
auth.settings.extra_fields['auth_user']= [
    Field('phone_number', 'string'),
    Field('address', 'text'),
    Field('city', 'string'),
    Field('zip', 'string'),
    Field('phone', 'string'),
    Field('birthday', 'date', requires = IS_DATE(format=('%d-%m-%Y')))]
auth.define_tables(username=True, signature=True)
```

In the controllers "default.py" I modify user like that.

```
def user():
    if request.args(0) == 'profile':
        for field in auth.settings.extra_fields['auth_user']:
            field.readable = field.writable = True
    return dict(form=auth())
```

I can't see new fields in registration form and in the table **auth_user**.
I miss something some where but I can't see what.

I use web2py 2.9.8 also tested with 2.9.5 and I have exactly the same comportment.

Answer (score 0):

> My extra file definition in **my_tables.py** is the problem. Web2py already have
>   **auth_user** definition in **db.py** models. You need to customize **db.py** and not add a new definition in a separate file.

Comment: Note, you can put the Auth code in a separate model file -- the problem was that you had the same code running twice in two different places -- just keep it in one place (doesn't have to be db.py). Also, keep in mind that the model files will be executed in alphabetical order.